# Merge many data frames by row names

Tags: r, merge, datatable, large-data

I am working on a project where I have 50 databases with the same structure.

Think of it the following way

```
df_1 <- data.frame(nationality=c("german","italian"), total=c(500,300), male=c(400,100))
df_2 <- data.frame(nationality=c("german","italian"), total=c(800,600), male=c(300,80))
```

and so on.

Basically, each dataframe contains data for a specific year. I would now like to have one dataframe per nationality where each column presents a year. The overall goal is to have a time data plot.

I am not able to find a solution to this problem, especially because I have so many data frames. I read that it would make sense to put them all in a list and then work with that, but I am not entirely sure if that would make sense.

Any help is highly appreciated, I am relatively new to R!

Comment: What's an example of how your data maps to year?

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Spring is asking, you have to annotate your data frames with the year before you can join, e.g. if you have your data frames in a named list, where the names are the years:

```
all_years <- list(year1 = df_1, year2 = df_2)
```

You could do something in tidyverse like:

```
library(tidyverse)
all_years %>% 
  names() %>% 
  map(\(year)
      {all_years[[year]] %>% rename_with(~paste(., year, sep="_"),
                                         -nationality)}) %>% 
  purrr::reduce(left_join, by="nationality") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-nationality, names_to="population_year") %>% 
  separate("population_year", c("population", "year"), sep="_") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(population,nationality), 
              names_from = year, 
              values_from = value) %>% 
  group_split(nationality) %>% 
  set_names(map(., ~.$nationality[1]))
```

The resulting list of tibbles contains

```
$german
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  population nationality year1 year2
  <chr>      <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 total      german        500   800
2 male       german        400   300

$italian
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  population nationality year1 year2
  <chr>      <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 total      italian       300   600
2 male       italian       100    80
```

This solution uses a join (and not bind) operation to be safer in case your data frames are not of equal format, e.g. ncol differs.

Answer (score 0):

An approach of first adding years to each data frame in a list, then splitting by *nationality*.

```
library(dplyr)

years <- c(2022, 2023) # one year per data frame

df_list <- list(df_1, df_2)

lapply(1:length(df_list), function(x) cbind(df_list[[x]], year=years[x])) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_split(nationality)
```

output

```
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    nationality: character
    total      : double
    male       : double
    year       : integer
  >
>[2]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  nationality total  male  year
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 german        500   400  2022
2 german        800   300  2023

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  nationality total  male  year
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 italian       300   100  2022
2 italian       600    80  2023
```

Comment: Alternate version with `imap` and `assign_in`: `df_list |> imap(\(df, i) assign_in(df, "year", years[i])) |> list_rbind()`

Comment: @andrew_reece ...although that leaves out the `split` part, right?

Comment: Yep - you already have `group_split` (could also use `group_nest`), I was just offering an alternative leading up to that point